# Distributed ProjectManagement/Bug Tracking

Tags: distributed, tracking

Now that we have DSCMs, are there any Project Management / Bug Tracking tools
that are distributed?

Comment: PS:
Preferably one that works with mercurial.
In the future I may move to git, so one that works with both mercurial and git would be doubly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

yes, I've played a little with [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki) that comes with several nice features:

- integrated, distributed bug tracking and distributed wiki
- built-in web interface (like hg serve) that supports deep archaeological digs through the project history
- all network communication via HTTP with proxy support so that everything works from behind restrictive firewalls
- everything (client, server, and utilities) is included in a single self-contained executable - trivial to install
- an entire project contained in single disk file (an SQLite database)

check also:

- [DITrack](http://www.ditrack.org/)
- [DisTract](http://www.distract.wellquite.org/)

Comment: When I asked I did not envision someone replying with a system that included it's own SCM. How does it compare with mercurial and git?

In particular does it support branching mechanisms ( cloning the repository, local branching where a repository contains multiple branches)?

Answer (score 8):

I've just been looking at this tonight, and have looked at Ditz.  Two others for consideration:

- [Bugs Everywhere](http://www.bugseverywhere.org/)
- [Artemis](http://www.mrzv.org/software/artemis/) (Mercurial extension)

Comment: BugsEverywhere looks interesting, but doesn't appear to work in Windows (a vanilla install, at least) due to its reliance on "make".  It might work with MSys or Cygwin.  Also, the documentation doesn't specify which version of Python is required, so I have no idea if it will work in Python 3 (or even if it will work with Python 2.6).

Comment: I bound up a copy of Bugs Everywhere as a self-contained executable with embedded python interpreter for Windows within http://www.nedprod.com/programs/Win32/BEurtle/. Simply add the dist directory in the Program Files\ned Productions\BEurtle folder to PATH and voila, you get bugs everywhere native on Windows. Note "be gui" launches BEurtle as the GUI separet from TortoiseXXX.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Written in

Python: [pitz](http://pitz.tplus1.com/)

Ruby: [ditz](http://ditz.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Ditz is no longer being maintained and does not work with Ruby 1.9.2.  Meanwhile, Pitz requires that you program your bugs using the Python interpreter and its object model - it doesn't have its own UI - which is a frankly bizarre way of recording bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[Rational Clearquest](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearquest/) provides a distributed software lifecycle management solution. It integrates with Clearcase (the related SCM) and, like Clearcase, is built to serve large distributed client bases.

Answer (score 0):

People already gave most important links, so let me add an alternative and a sidenote.

Alternative: emacs org-mode has sophisticated support for making and using task lists. And .org file is just a text file, so can be versioned as anything else. That's probably not the only option, other GUIs/editors may support similar tools (Eclipse Mylyn?)

Sidenote: I've been using bugs everywhere for some time. Well, it was easy and pleasant to quickly drop todo's. And it was close to impossible to manage the issue list once it grown big. Really, it is the time when one needs milestones, issue classification, progress tracking, some reports...

ditz may be more promising here as it has some HTML reports and ditz-commander. I haven't tested it, though.