# What is the state of distributed bug tracking?

Tags: git, distributed, issue-tracking

Some years ago, there was some activity here on SO regarding distributed bug tracking systems:

- [Distributed ProjectManagement/Bug Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773818/distributed-projectmanagement-bug-tracking)
- [Distributed Revision Control, Wiki, and Bug-Tracking all in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170831/distributed-revision-control-wiki-and-bug-tracking-all-in-one)

Some systems are existing which seem more or less active:

- [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org) (looks quite mature, especially because it has got a graphical UI but brings in it's own version control system and I don't want to switch away from Git)
- [BugsEverywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/) (seems active but lacks graphical UI except it's Tortoise integration [BEurtle](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/Win32/BEurtle/))
- some others listed [here](http://www.cs.unb.ca/~bremner/blog/posts/git-issue-trackers/) (VCS agnostic and specific ones)

I'm wondering: **what's the current state of distributed bug tracking?** Is it still in some kind of hackers-only phase (which makes it hardly usable for the average GUI-loving developer) or am I missing something?

Also, while I find this topic **very** interesting since it integrates perfectly with distributed version control systems, it seems that most projects started some time ago are dead in the meanwhile. Is my impression true? Why is there no activity in this field?

Comment: https://github.com/MichaelMure/git-bug Here’s another related project

Answer (score 4):

I have been very interesting of this topic as well, but unfortunately it seems to have been a real let-down.

[Ditz](http://ditz.rubyforge.org/) was in my opinion one of the most promising projects, but it does not seem to have had much activity since 2008.

I remember there was a lot of hype in blog posts years ago, and an equal number of projects, but for some reason all of them seem to have died/stagnated.

I believe part of the problem is that most open source projects are using third party hosting sites, and there hasn't yet been a good enough distributed issue tracker that would also provide an interface that could be integrated easily with such hosting sites.

This is certainly a much-neglected segment in the open source world, waiting for the killer-project that could raise the critical mass of interest...